# Error 404 received in Godaddy (.htaccess or web.config)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Good day.

I set up a website and here's the link:

http://xactosdatosinc.com/ci/codeigniter

In my local PC, I setup a .htaccess file to have a clean URL which is working. When I uploaded it in Godaddy, I can view the login page. But when I tried to login, it says, Error 404.

I search a lot of variations of .htaccess but no success at all. Actually, here's mine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)`
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

At one point, I realized that in my local PC, I am using an Apache server thats why `.htaccess` is working. In Godaddy, I believe, `.htaccess` is not recognized. It is `web.config` that is being used in their ISS webserver.

My issue now is how can I translate this `.htaccess` to `web.config` which I hope works in Godaddy hosting?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL Rewriting under IIS at GoDaddy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416727/url-rewriting-under-iis-at-godaddy)

Comment: Hi Phil, thank you for your reply. But Jon provided a code below which I applied. But there's only a missing XML tags which is detailed below... Anyhows, thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First result on google: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="htaccess codeigniter rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/index.php" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/resources" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/robots.txt" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Hi Jon Lin, thanks a lot... but definitely there's only one thing that is missing in the code your provided... Add the the XML tags <configuration> and <system.webServer> before the tag <rewrite> and its closing tags  </system.webServer> </configuration>...